# Javascript issue with click event on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, navigation

Recently I took over a WordPress site using a theme that has got a lot of limitations. One of which is their navigation menu. If you look at this site (http://chefkevinwarren.com/) you'll see the drop down menu only shows up on click. Not hover or mouseover. Problem really is when you click on one area with a drop down and then click on another button with a drop down, the first drop down does not go away. Only, it seems clicking outside the drop downs do they disappear. Not great by any stretch.

I found the code and switched the click events to mouseover events. Figured that would work, right? It did, but too well. Now the drop downs go away as soon as you leave the main button. This isn't any better, of course.

The code is too long for SO, so I pasted it into PasteBin, if anyone wants to take a peek: http://pastebin.com/S4Xg9FQa

Comment: can you change it back to a click event for a bit - just in order to see how it was working before - plus the menu can't be used in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

your code is soo complexe for such simple approach. so if you are looking for a simple DropDown Menu, then here is a Demo:

DEMO: **(UPDATED)** https://jsfiddle.net/9n514f08/2/

**JS:** **(UPDATED)**

```
var animating = false;
$(".TREE .NODE").mouseenter(function(){
    animating = true;
    $(this).find(".NODES").slideDown("fast",function(){
        animating = false;    
    });
});

$(".TREE .NODE").mouseleave(function(){
    animating = true;
    $(this).find(".NODES").slideUp("fast",function(){
        animating = false;    
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="TREE">
    <div class="NODE">
        <a class="NODE-LINK">ABOUT</a>
        <div class="NODES">
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">MY STORY</a>
            </div>
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">MY STYLE</a>
            </div>
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">MY STYLE X</a>
            </div>
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">MY STYLE Y</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><div class="NODE">
        <a class="NODE-LINK">SERVICE</a>
        <div class="NODES">
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">MY PRICING</a>
            </div>
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">SERVICES</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.TREE{
    background: #3f4c6b;
}

.TREE > .NODE{
    background: #313654;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #3f4c6b;
    position: relative;
}
.TREE > .NODE:FIRST-CHILD{
    border-left: 0px solid #000;
}
.TREE > .NODE:LAST-CHILD{
    border-right: 0px solid #000;
}

.TREE > .NODE:HOVER{
    background: #3f4c6b;
}

.TREE > .NODE a.NODE-LINK{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
}

.TREE > .NODE .NODES{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    background: #3f4c6b;
    padding: 5px;
    display: none;
}

.TREE > .NODE .NODES .NODE a.NODE-LINK{
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.TREE > .NODE .NODES .NODE:HOVER{
    background: #313654;
}
```

if you want the DropMenu do show on click, then change

```
$(".TREE .NODE").mouseenter(function(){
        .....
```

to this

```
$(".TREE .NODE").click(function(){
       .....
```

Comment: A really simple drop down menu doesn't need JavaScript, or at least doesn't need JavaScript to handle the animations. For instance there are already problems with your example, in that you can hover over each menu item multiple times and they just keep animating up and down. For simple take a CSS only or minimal JS approach.

Comment: Though I will upvote your answer if you fix the problem - shouldn't spread this code to people who don't understand how to address the problem.

Comment: @TroyThompson, i stated that my Code is a DEMO of how to implement such JS animated DropDown Menu. its not for copy+paste, though i updated it. but you can continue downVoting. "great" job

Comment: No offense, I just don't think your post offered him a reasonable way to fix his problem. Yes your advice is fine generally though. Plus I see a lot of interactive components that allow for multiple events to queue up like that and no UI should behave like that so I made note of it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible quick fix would be to edit the JavaScript controlling your menu.

On line 785 of light-dose.js - add ".children(".dropdown-slide").slideUp( throttle);

```
$( this ).parent().toggleClass( 'open' ).siblings().removeClass( 'open' ).children(".dropdown-slide").slideUp( throttle );
```

Test that out and see if it works for you.